# Cockburn Use Case Template

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to create a Cockburn use case table and this is what I could do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]    

\def\arraystretch{1.5}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|}

\hline
    Use Case \#N                   & \multicolumn{3}   {l|}{Name}   \\ \hline
    Goal in Context                & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{This is a very long line. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  } \\ \hline
    Preconditions                  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}       \\ \hline
    Success End Conditions         & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}       \\ \hline
    Failed End Conditions          & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}       \\ \hline
    Primary Actor                  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}       \\ \hline
    Trigger                        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}       \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Description}   & Step & User Action & System \\ \cline{2-4} 
    &      &             &        \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Extensions}    & Step & User Action & System \\ \cline{2-4} 
    &      &             &        \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Subvariations} & Step & User Action & System \\ \cline{2-4} 
    &      &             &        \\ \hline
    Notes                          & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}       \\ \hline


\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It seemed to work well but long lines will break it and I couldn't find a way to wrap long text without ruining something else (i.e. multicolumn), can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

I saw another post about Cockburn template but that was not exactly what I was looking for as I am trying to reproduce the table I was shown in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the long entry to be an X column with more or less three times the usual X width as it is spanning 3 X columns, but also 2 lots of inter-column space and two vertical rules

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]    

\def\arraystretch{1.5}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|}

  \hline Use Case \#N & \multicolumn{3} {l|}{Name} \\ \hline Goal in
  Context & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr 3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    This is a very long line. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua.  } \\
 \hline Preconditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
 \hline Success End Conditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
 \hline Failed End Conditions &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
 \hline Primary Actor &
  \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
 \hline Trigger & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\

  \hline \multirow{2}{*}{Description} & Step & User Action & System \\

  \cline{2-4} & & & \\
 \hline \multirow{2}{*}{Extensions} & Step &
  User Action & System \\
 \cline{2-4} & & & \\
 \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Subvariations} & Step & User Action & System \\

  \cline{2-4} & & & \\
 \hline Notes & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \\
 \hline


\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but is the `+4` supposed to be there? Maybe `\dimexpr`?

Comment: @samcarter sorry this etex stuff is a bit modern for me....

Comment: @vvvmimi make sure you get the fixed version after samcarter's comment!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Score of useful comments about answers: Samcarter 1 : DavidCarlisle 99999999 => I'm catching up, we'll be even soon :)

Comment: @samcarter still you are _way_ ahead of egreg

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :)